# Debug VS Release apk

Tags: android, cordova

When i run
`ionic build android`
it produces a fully functional app.

When I run `cordova build --release android`it fails at one of the critical screens.

Error happens when I login to facebook. At this point there is interaction with Firebase and then it makes a call to the server.
It still loads the next screen like i was logged in, but it doesn't populate items from server.

Problem that I cant debug because it is release version.

Comment: Are you using proguard?

Comment: @TheSunny no i do not

Comment: Are you using different flavours? I have never used cordova but with gradle based Android projects different flavours can sometimes to completely different things. I.e having different API keys depending on dev and full/release app.

Comment: @TheSunny flavours? And for android release you add keys and run build for android. So its very strange how some feature doesnt work

Comment: [This](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html).